# Abstracting actions on different tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

I have several tables, for example: `Cats`, `Dogs`, and `Rabbits`. Each table has two fields: the integer primary key `XId` and the string `XName`, where `X` is the name of the table: `Cat`, `Dog` or `Rabbit`.

Then, I have a `string[]` for each table which contain names. I need to sync the table with the array: remove table records that do not have their names listed in the array, and add new records for names that exist in the array only.

The easiest approach would have been copying the code three times and changing `CatName` to `DogName`, etc. in all places. However, I'm looking for a more clean solution that does not duplicate code.

If it was not a table but a simple `IList<T>`, I would have written the following snippet:

```
void SyncData<T>(IList<T> source, string[] names, Func<T, string> nameGetter, Func<string, T> creator)
{
    var toRemove = source.Where(x => !names.Contains(nameGetter(x))).ToArray();
    foreach(var item in toRemove)
        source.Remove(item);

    var toCreate = names.Where(x => !source.Any(i => nameGetter(i) != x)).ToArray();
    foreach(var item in toCreate)
        source.Add(creator(item));
}

SyncData(cats, catNames, c => c.CatName, n => new Cat { CatName = n });
SyncData(dogs, dogNames, d => d.DogName, n => new Dog { DogName = n });
...
```

Can something similar be achieved for `IQueryable<T>`? Unluckily, it doesn't work as-is, because the LINQ provider cannot translate function calls to SQL queries.

Since the field names are different, I cannot make a common interface for my objects. Changing the POCO class definitions is also not an option.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [**Linq.Dynamic**](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/), it's possible to achieve that.

And `IQueryable<T>` doesn't have `Add` method, so we need to use `IDbSet<T>` or something similar.

You can try this.

```
public static class SyncExtension
{
    public static void SyncData<T>(
        this IDbSet<T> source, 
        string[] names, 
        Expression<Func<T, string>> name, 
        Func<string, T> creator) where T : class
    {
        var columnName = ((MemberExpression)name.Body).Member.Name;

        var removePredicate = string.Format("!{0}.Contains(@0)", columnName);
        var toRemove = source.Where(removePredicate, names).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in toRemove)
            source.Remove(item);

        var addPredicate = string.Format("{0} = @0", columnName);
        var toCreate = names.Where(x => 
            !source.Where(addPredicate, x).Any()).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in toCreate)
            source.Add(creator(item));
    }
}
```

Usage.

```
using (var db = new AppContext())
{
    var names = new[] { "A", "B" };
    db.Set<Cat>().SyncData(names, x => x.Name, x => new Cat { Name = x });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```